# Для чего задан параметр?

Tags: java

Задача.
Напишите программу, которая должна прочитать два значения из System.in:

количество людей
количество кусочков в одной пицце.
Гарантируется, что входные параметры — целые положительные числа.

Программа должна напечатать минимальное количество пицц (не ноль), которое надо заказать, чтобы у всех было одинаковое количество ломтиков и не осталось ни одного лишнего.

```
public class PizzaSplit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int people = scanner.nextInt();
        int pieces = scanner.nextInt();
        int pizza = 1;
        int countOfPiec = pieces;

        while(people > 0) {
            pieces = countOfPiec;
            pieces *= pizza;
            if(pieces % people == 0){
                break;
            }
            pizza++;
        }
        System.out.println(pizza);


    }
}
```

Обратился к интернету за решением задачи, но так и не понял для чего задается параметр
int countOfPiec = pieces; и потом вновь задается в цикле в виде pieces = countOfPiec; Почему если избавить код от этих двух строчек отображается неверный результат?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка `int countOfPiec = pieces;` инициализирует значение переменной countOfPiec. Она хранит значение `pieces` для того, чтобы в цикле сбрасывать значение переменной `pieces`.
В цикле же у вас идет перебор различных значений `pizza`.

К примеру, допустим, что задано `people = 3` и `pieces = 2`.

Разбор итераций цикла построчно:

**pizza = 1:**

1. `pieces = countOfPiec`  == 2 (сбрасываем значение pieces)
2. `pieces *= 1`  == 2 (получаем общее количество кусков для текущего значения пицц)
3. `pieces % people`  == 2 % 3 == 2 != 0 (условие проверяет, хватит ли кусков пиццы, чтобы поровну разделить на каждого. Сейчас оно не выполняется, идем дальше)
4. `pizza++` == 2

**pizza = 2:**

1. `pieces = countOfPiec`  == 2 (сбрасываем значение pieces)
2. `pieces *= 2` == 4 (общее количество кусков)
3. `pieces % people`  == 4 % 3 == 1 != 0, идем дальше
4. `pizza++` == 3

**pizza = 3:**

1. `pieces = countOfPiec`  == 2 (сбрасываем значение pieces)
2. `pieces *= 3` == 6 (общее количество кусков)
3. `pieces % people`  == 6 % 3 == 0 - условие выполнено, программа завершается

Переменная `countOfPiec` в данном алгоритме, как вы можете заметить, необходима. Без нее у вас значение `pieces` не будет сбрасываться, и следовательно программа будет выполняться не верно.

Вообще, эта задача затрагивает темы поиска **НОК** и **НОД** (наим. общее кратное и наиб. общий делитель), поэтому советую прочитать алгоритмы на эту тему. В вашем случае вам нужно найти НОК, чем будет являться общее количество кусков пиццы. Для получения ответа необходимо будет разделить НОК на изначальное количество кусков, получите такой же ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
        pieces = countOfPiec;
        pieces *= pizza;
```

->

```
        pieces = countOfPiec;
        pieces = pieces * pizza;
```

->

```
        pieces = countOfPiec * pizza;
```

Другими словами вы пробуете одну пиццу порезанную на `countOfPiec` кусков, затем две пиццы, затем три и так далее.

Если строку `pieces = countOfPiec;` убрать, то вы попробуете `pizza` кусков, `pizza^2` кусков, `pizza^3` кусков и дальше. То есть будете идти большими шагами. А так есть шанс пропустить правильное решение.

**P.S.** Задачу можно решить без перебора. Нужное количество пицц вычисляется с помощью одного трюка.